# Editing an object in Entity Framework 6

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-6

I have an object Employee containing lots of information on an Employee, such as his Login, Name, LastName, e-mail address etc.

After retrieving all the information imputed on the edit page of an employee, I then call the following to update the object :

```
 public Employee Edit(Employee objEmployee) // Work on EDIT
 {
    var Original = Get(objEmployee.Login);
    _entities.Employees.Add(objEmployee);           
    _entities.SaveChanges();
    return objEmployee;
 }
```

Once it reaches `SaveChanges()` I get the following :

```
System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbUpdateException was caught
  HResult=-2146233087
  Message=An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details.
  Source=EntityFramework
  StackTrace:
       at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.SaveChanges()
       at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.SaveChanges()
       at System.Data.Entity.DbContext.SaveChanges()
       at CRAWebSiteMVC.Models.EntityEmployeeManagerRepository.Edit(Employee objEmployee) in c:\Users\kade\Source\Workspaces\InfoCubedProjects\CRA\CRAWebSiteMVC\Models\Employee\EntityEmployeeManagerRepository.cs:line 26
       at CRAWebSiteMVC.Models.EmployeeManagerService.Edit(Employee objEmployee) in c:\Users\kade\Source\Workspaces\InfoCubedProjects\CRA\CRAWebSiteMVC\Models\Employee\EmployeeManagerService.cs:line 113
  InnerException: System.Data.Entity.Core.UpdateException
       HResult=-2146233087
       Message=An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details.
       Source=EntityFramework
       StackTrace:
            at System.Data.Entity.Core.Mapping.Update.Internal.UpdateTranslator.Update()
            at System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.Internal.EntityAdapter.<Update>b__2(UpdateTranslator ut)
            at System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.Internal.EntityAdapter.Update[T](T noChangesResult, Func`2 updateFunction)
            at System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.Internal.EntityAdapter.Update()
            at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.<SaveChangesToStore>b__d()
            at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.ExecuteInTransaction[T](Func`1 func, IDbExecutionStrategy executionStrategy, Boolean startLocalTransaction, Boolean releaseConnectionOnSuccess)
            at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.SaveChangesToStore(SaveOptions options, IDbExecutionStrategy executionStrategy, Boolean startLocalTransaction)
            at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.<>c__DisplayClassb.<SaveChangesInternal>b__8()
            at System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.Execute[TResult](Func`1 operation)
            at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.SaveChangesInternal(SaveOptions options, Boolean executeInExistingTransaction)
            at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.SaveChanges(SaveOptions options)
            at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.SaveChanges()
       InnerException: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException
            HResult=-2146232060
            Message=Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_EMPLOYEE'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.Employee'.
The statement has been terminated.
            Source=.Net SqlClient Data Provider
            ErrorCode=-2146232060
            Class=14
            LineNumber=1
            Number=2627
            Procedure=""
            Server=MMSDEVNEW\SQL2008
            State=1
            StackTrace:
                 at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
                 at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
                 at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
                 at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)
                 at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds, RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString)
                 at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean async, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite, SqlDataReader ds)
                 at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method, TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite)
                 at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.InternalExecuteNonQuery(TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, String methodName, Boolean sendToPipe, Int32 timeout, Boolean asyncWrite)
                 at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
                 at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbCommandDispatcher.<NonQuery>b__0(DbCommand t, DbCommandInterceptionContext`1 c)
                 at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.InternalDispatcher`1.Dispatch[TTarget,TInterceptionContext,TResult](TTarget target, Func`3 operation, TInterceptionContext interceptionContext, Action`3 executing, Action`3 executed)
                 at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbCommandDispatcher.NonQuery(DbCommand command, DbCommandInterceptionContext interceptionContext)
                 at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InterceptableDbCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
                 at System.Data.Entity.Core.Mapping.Update.Internal.DynamicUpdateCommand.Execute(Dictionary`2 identifierValues, List`1 generatedValues)
                 at System.Data.Entity.Core.Mapping.Update.Internal.UpdateTranslator.Update()
            InnerException:
```

> Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_EMPLOYEE'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.Employee'.

What could be causing that, and how may I solve it?

Comment: Because you adding a new object with the same ID (PK value), not updating the existing

Comment: Understood, and how may I update the existing object?

Comment: You could use `db.Entry(objEmployee).State = EntityState.Modified; db.SaveChanges();` but I'm confused why your using `var Original = Get(objEmployee.Login);` (you never use it) - were you intending to map the value from `objEmployee` to `Original` and then save `Original`?

Comment: Changing it to Modified gives me the following error :
" Attaching an entity of type 'CRAWebSiteMVC.Models.Employee' failed because another entity of the same type already has the same primary key value. This can happen when using the 'Attach' method or setting the state of an entity to 'Unchanged' or 'Modified' if any entities in the graph have conflicting key values. "

Additionally, Original has no use right now.

Comment: Did you delete the `_entities.Employees.Add(objEmployee);` line?

Comment: With or without it the error occurs at the `_entities.Entry(objEmployee).State` line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to update the entity and not to re-insert it:

```
public Employee Edit(Employee objEmployee) // Work on EDIT
{

    _entities.Employees.Attach(objEmployee);   
    var entity = _entities.Entry(objEmployee);  
    entry.State = EntityState.Modified;      // Mark as modified

    _entities.SaveChanges();
    return objEmployee;
}
```

Comment: var entity = Db.Entry(objEmployee);  

Should that be `var entry = _entity.Entry(objEmployee);` ?

Comment: Sadly, as I told @StephenMuecke I have received the same error :
`Attaching an entity of type 'CRAWebSiteMVC.Models.Employee' failed because another entity of the same type already has the same primary key value. This can happen when using the 'Attach' method or setting the state of an entity to 'Unchanged' or 'Modified' if any entities in the graph have conflicting key values` once I land on `Attach`.

Comment: This is usually because your entity is not being tracked correctly and has become detached.

Comment: Being new to the technology, I have no clue what tracking consists of. I'll look into it, thank you.